# Why am I getting strange results from CUDADot?

Tags: evaluation, cudalink

This is what I am getting:

[image]

This is what I am expecting:

[image]

Comment: Please provide code that can be copied; don't force people to retype things just to help you.

Comment: The red is usually an indicator that a function has been defined multiple times, I think. Have you tried closing Mathematica, reopening it, and trying this in a new notebook? Perhaps a package you are using has defined `CUDADot` as something else – something incorrect?